# Top local cohomology - recommendations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra

I need some background in local cohomology to read a certain paper, which exploits the structure of the top local cohomology. Even after acquainting myself to local cohomology, I fail to understand the significance of the top local cohomology group. What would be a nice resource to understand the intuition behind the information that is held by the top local cohomology group?

Comment: You can define local cohomology for topological spaces (and singular cohomology), or for algebraic varieties (and $\ell$-adic/de Rham/... cohomlogy). In all cases, the local cohomology of closed subspace $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$ defined in terms of the six functors to be $i^!k_X$, where $k_X$ is the constant sheaf on $X$. When both spaces are smooth or $i$ is a regular embedding, this is just (a shift of) the constant sheaf. Thus, the local cohomology (and presumably the top degree part too) measures the singular behaviour "in the normal direction".

Comment: I presume you have looked at Grothedieck's Local Cohomology, pages 30 and 64, where these groups are related to Ext groups and dualizing modules.  Apologies if this is obvious, as I have only consulted this one source.

Comment: A common structure in commutative algebra is to consider $H^d_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)$ where $R$ is local Noetherian.  That local cohomology module is the Matlis dual of $\omega_R$, the canonical module of $R$ (assuming one exists, for instance if $R$ is complete or finite type over a field or $Z$).  There are lots of other things one might say too.  In particular, one way to study anything about the canonical module is to instead study the local cohomology module.

Answer (score 7):

Associated to a ring $R$ and ideal $I\leq R$ we have a scheme $X=\text{spec}(R)$ and a closed subscheme $Z=\text{spec}(R/I)$ with complement $U=X\setminus Z$ (which will typically not be an affine scheme, unless $I$ is principal).  Now the local cohomology $H^*_I(R)$ is just the relative sheaf cohomology $H^*(X,U;\mathcal{O}_X)$.

A typical case is when $X=\mathbb{A}^n$ and $Z=\{0\}$ so $U=\mathbb{A}^n\setminus\{0\}$.  The local cohomology $H^{*}(\mathbb{A}^n,\mathbb{A}^n\setminus{\{0\}};\mathcal{O})$ is naturally compared with the ordinary singular cohomology $H^{*}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})$.  The pair $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})$ is homotopy equivalent to the pair $(B^n,S^{n-1})$, so the cohomology is the same as the reduced cohomology of the quotient $B^n/S^{n-1}\simeq S^n$.  In other words, we have $H^{n}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})\simeq\mathbb{Z}$, and the other cohomology groups are zero.  This makes it unsurprising that $H^{k}(\mathbb{A}^n,\mathbb{A}^n\setminus{\{0\}};\mathcal{O})$ is zero for $k\neq n$, and that the interesting case is when $k=n$.  The actual value of the $n$'th local cohomology is not visible from this line of argument, however.